# Is CPU idle during an infinite loop?

Tags: performance, batch-file, cpu-usage

Below is a paragraph from the book **Java Performance: The definitive guide.**

> You write a simple script containing an infinite loop. When that
>   script is executed, it will consume 100% of a CPU. The following batch
>   job will do just that in Windows:
>
> ```
> ECHO OFF   
> :BEGIN  
> ECHO LOOPING   
> GOTO BEGIN  
> REM We never get here...   
> ECHO DONE
> ```
>
> Consider what it would mean if this script did not consume 100% of a
>   CPU. It would mean that the operating system had something it could
>   do—it could print yet another line saying LOOPING, ***but it chose
>   instead to be idle***. Being idle doesn’t help anyone in that case,
>   and if we were doing a useful (lengthy) calculation, forcing the CPU
>   to be periodically idle would mean that it would take longer to get
>   the answer we are after.

I am finding it hard to understand why an infinite loop would keep the CPU idle?

Comment: This is the wrong site for non programming specific questions, try [Super User](http://superuser.com/about) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the text -- infinite loops do take up ALL available CPU cycles.

When the book said "*but it chose instead to be idle*" it is just saying that if an infinite loop script did not take 100% of the CPU, then it could have decided to become idle for some cycles (which is never the case because it is a waste of available processing power).